# Upgrade from 7.3.4 to 7.8.1 Umbraco - Umbraco.Web.Editors.ContentController - Unhandled controller exception occurred

Tags: umbraco

**Issue:**

After upgrading Umbraco for a client, they can no longer create content. We upgraded them from 7.3.4 to 7.8.1:

https://our.umbraco.org/download/releases/compare?from=7.3.4&to=7.8.1#issuesTasks

**The error being thrown on the front end is:**

"Failed to retrieve data for empty content item type"

[image]

**And back end log is:**

```
 2018-03-06 20:25:27,723 [P832/D2/T16] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Editors.ContentController - Unhandled controller exception occurred System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated()    at Umbraco.Web.Security.WebSecurity.ValidateCurrentUser(Boolean throwExceptions, Boolean requiresApproval)    at Umbraco.Web.WebApi.UmbracoAuthorizedApiController.get_UmbracoUser()    at Umbraco.Web.Editors.ContentController.GetEmpty(String contentTypeAlias, Int32 parentId)    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Any ideas what needs to be done?

**Notes:**

- https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/7ee510ed386495120666a78c61497f58ff05de8f/src/Umbraco.Web/Security/WebSecurity.cs
- I debugged umbraco and this is where it's stopping:

[image]

[image]

- I seem to have an http context on loading the nodes just fine, it's only when i go to create content of any type.
- I wonder if this is relevant?

  ```
  public class UnityConfig
  {
      private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
      {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
          RegisterTypes(container);
          return container;
      });

      public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
      {
          return container.Value;
      }

      public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
      {
          container.RegisterType<UmbracoContext>(
              new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
              new InjectionFactory(c => UmbracoContext.Current));

          container.RegisterType<HealthCheckController>(new InjectionConstructor());
          container.RegisterType<UserTreeController>(new  InjectionConstructor());
          container.RegisterType<Umbraco.Web.Editors.UsersController>(new  InjectionConstructor());
          container.RegisterType<LegacyTreeController>(new InjectionConstructor());

          container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UmbracoUnitOfWork>();
          container.RegisterType<IServices, UmbracoServices>();
      }
  }
  ```

or this:

```
public class UmbracoWebAPIHttpControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly DefaultHttpControllerActivator defaultHttpControllerActivator;

    public UmbracoWebAPIHttpControllerActivator()
    {
        this.defaultHttpControllerActivator = new DefaultHttpControllerActivator();
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (this.IsUmbracoController(controllerType))
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType) as IHttpController;
        }

        return this.defaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(request, controllerDescriptor, controllerType);
    }

    private bool IsUmbracoController(Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType.Namespace != null
            && (!controllerType.Namespace.StartsWith("test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My unity container registration:

```
    container.RegisterType<UmbracoContext>(
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionFactory(c => UmbracoContext.Current));
```

needed to be:

```
        container.RegisterType<UmbracoContext>(
            new TransientLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c => UmbracoContext.Current));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396